# OSError: [Errno 28] inotify watch limit reached

Tags: python, heroku, streamlit, heroku-api

I am making a python-based web app using Streamlit. After deploying it in Heroku, the build succeeds but there is an application error. I don't have any idea where in the source code this error is being generated. Please help me!
The error :

````
2022-07-18T18:55:37.985429+00:00 app[web.1]:     Inotify._raise_error()
2022-07-18T18:55:37.985439+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/watchdog/observers/inotify_c.py", line 398, in _raise_error
2022-07-18T18:55:37.985636+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise OSError(errno.ENOSPC, "inotify watch limit reached")
2022-07-18T18:55:37.985677+00:00 app[web.1]: OSError: [Errno 28] inotify watch limit reached
2022-07-18T18:55:38.387667+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-07-18T18:55:38.510041+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-07-18T18:55:48.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2022-07-18T18:57:33.589417+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=invezto.herokuapp.com request_id=bc8f4556-852e-4dad-8b67-71e49ffaaf23 fwd="49.37.45.19" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-07-18T18:57:33.917128+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=invezto.herokuapp.com request_id=46e2e615-17dc-42f6-a86d-4dfc5fd5ecfc fwd="49.37.45.19" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https ```
````

Answer (score 16):

Adding option `--server.fileWatcherType none` at the command line helped me to resolve similar issue. A full example would look like this:

```
streamlit run app.py --server.fileWatcherType none
```

More solutions [here](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/oserror-errno-24-inotify-instance-limit-reached/5506)

Comment: Note that my answer, although not the popular vote,  keeps file watching turned on, a nice feature for debugging live.

Answer (score 8):

Streamlit recursively monitors changes in the parent folder of the application script, e.g. `app.py` [[source]](https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit/blob/develop/lib/streamlit/watcher/event_based_path_watcher.py#L170).

The idea is that if source files update, the app is 'rerun', as a convenience for app development. However, if this folder contains too many subfolders and subfiles, apparently [`watchdog`](https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/quickstart.html) reaches a limit and raises an error. This easily happens if you run straight from your home directory, which contains tons of configuration files, etc. Or maybe when you run from a git repository with numerous files in `.git`  (just speculating).

You can resolve this by either placing the `app.py` script in a (sub)folder than only contains dependencies that you'll edit during development, or by `--server.fileWatcherType none` and accept the nuisance of manually restarting.

```
streamlit run app.py --server.fileWatcherType none
```

(as suggested by @swwt)

Comment: +1 for pointing out the consequences of setting this to none. When deploying a Streamlit app, it's perfectly fine to disable it then.

Answer (score 0):

This actually happened to me due to "opening folders" in Visual studio Code.  Running on linux.  When I started vscode with other streamlit python files open.  Then started/Opened a folder project Python/Django from another directory within a larger code directory/repository. However it started adding all the files in the root folder to the watch list.

There are thousands of files in the root from other projects.

~notebooks/work/dev
~notebooks/personal/dev

Each with different projects in them.

The new django projects was ~notebooks/work/dev/djangoproject

Vscode was watching everything all the way down to ~notebooks

Streamlit would then complain.  Something akin to too many open file handles.

It took a day or so to realize the culprit.  I closed out the folder, and just opened the files from the other streamlit projects and it was fine from then on.